# How do i regain access and permissions to an entire drive?

Tags: hard-drive, security, permissions

iwanted to upgrade my windows but didn't want to format my data drive coz it's huge and i couldn't transfer to external HD so i formatted the windows drive and installed new version of windows and now i can't open any of the files on the data drive and iam denied access , i tried to fix this by changing the owner in the security tab inside properties but this is very time consujing coz i have thousands of files as i am a university proffessors in all formats

my question is there a way i can regain access for the entire data drive all together one time vwithout having to repeat the steps for each single file ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do it once:

- Open Explorer
- Right-click the drive and choose Properties
- Go to the Security tab and click Advanced
- Click the Change owner button as you already did
- Check the option of "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object"
- Click OK.

[image]